# How to disable registration new users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel. I want to disable registration for new users but I need the login to work.

How can I disable the registration forms, routes, and controllers?

Comment: Just remove the register-related methods from your **routes.php** file. _Don’t_ override the methods with blank ones—it’s a horrible and hack-y approach as you’ve then got to re-add the bodies if you decide to re-enable that feature in the future.

Comment: @MartinBean there are no routes in `routes.php`. To enable the authentication functions, all you do is add `Route::auth();` to the file.

Comment: @miken32 My comment was from over five months ago, before the `Route::auth()` shortcut was advocated.

Comment: if you are in laravel 5.5 and above   `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);` in web.php

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Laravel 5.7 introduced the following functionality:

```php
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

The currently possible options here are:

```php
Auth::routes([
  'register' => false, // Registration Routes...
  'reset' => false, // Password Reset Routes...
  'verify' => false, // Email Verification Routes...
]);
```

For older Laravel versions just override `showRegistrationForm()` and `register()` methods in

- `AuthController` for Laravel 5.0 - 5.4
- `Auth/RegisterController.php` for Laravel 5.5

```php
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return redirect('login');
}

public function register()
{

}
```

Comment: It might be wise to also change the create() function to:         throw new Exception('Registration not possible');

Comment: or you can add `abort(404)` on `function register()`

Comment: I wouldn’t advocate this approach, as overloading code to remove a feature is never a good thing. Just don’t register the registration-related routes.

Comment: This does not work for me. First of all, I do not see these methods in the overload menu, and second, even if I add them, they do nothing. My request gets the same 302 response. I want to remove the register/auth logic as a whole, I do not need it. Is there any way to do this easily? I tried deleting AuthController and the unnecessary routes, still did nothing.

Comment: You should disable the POST as well

Comment: @MartinBean "overloading code to remove a feature is never a good thing" - why? BTW it's overriding not overloading.

Comment: Works, but without the register override.. else I cant login anymore.

Comment: For Laravel 5.5, put this in `Auth/RegisterController.php`

Comment: It should be noted that as of 5.6 this functionality is now kept in the 'RegisterUsers.php' trait

Comment: In Laravel 5.7 `showRegistrationForm()` function is in `vendor` folder, technically it's **not recommended** to edit files in vendor folder. Basically what I recommend is to remove register route from `web.php`. You can simply say `Auth::routes(['register' => false])` in `web.php` file. Cheers!

Comment: Still work on Laravel v8

Answer (score 68):

This might be new in 5.7, but there is now an options array to the auth method. Simply changing

```
Auth::routes();
```

to

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

in your routes file after running `php artisan make:auth` will disable user registration.

Comment: Thanks for this, I don't know since which version it exists, but I think it is the right path for disabling registration part !

Comment: It was [added](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25556) in 5.7.

Comment: Disable Register Route in Laravel 7 / 8

Answer (score 56):

If you're using Laravel 5.2 and you installed the auth related functionality with `php artisan make:auth` then your `app/Http/routes.php` file will include all auth-related routes by simply calling `Route::auth()`.

The auth() method can be found in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`. So if you want to do as some people suggest here and disable registration by removing unwanted routes (probably a good idea) then you have to copy the routes you still want from the auth() method and put them in `app/Http/routes.php` (replacing the call to Route::auth()). So for instance:

```
<?php
// This is app/Http/routes.php

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes... removed!

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

If you're using lower version than 5.2 then it's probably different, I remember things changed quite a bit since 5.0, at some point `artisan make:auth` was even removed IIRC.

Comment: Instead of remove the registration routes, is it possible to enable them only for a particular type of users?

Comment: @Sefran2 You can achieve this by associating groups with middleware. Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups

Comment: First of all, I tried `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
 Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
 Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
});`, but when the logged user requests `/register` he is redirected to `/`

Comment: @Sefran2 That's because AuthController calls (via other classes and traits, it's a little convoluted) the middleware `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`. And that middleware redirects you to `/` if you're already logged in. Which makes sense, why would you want to register if you're logged in? :-)  If you want to only allow some routes to some types of users, you'll need to create your own middleware instead of `['middleware' => 'auth']`

Comment: For 5.3 they are different once again, but can still be found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

Answer (score 38):

For Laravel 5.3 and 5.4, here is the proper way to do it:

You have to change:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

to

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

in **app/Http/Controller/Auth/RegisterController.php**

Comment: nice job! I think this way also protects from POST request for creating user via post?

Comment: this will allow registered users to see the registration page which you would not want

Comment: Use middleware("auth") then middleware("guest") to bypass registration page for everyone

Comment: then a auth user  can register a  new  user  in this case.

Comment: Yes this is the only proper way for anything below  5.7  .. how is this not the selected answer

Answer (score 38):

As of Laravel 5.7 you can pass an array of options to `Auth::routes()`. You can then disable the register routes with:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

You can see how this works from the source code: [src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1152).

Comment: In my opinion, this is the correct answer. Nice found!

Answer (score 27):

## Method 1 for version 5.3

In laravel 5.3 don't have AuthController.
to disable register route you should change in constructor of `RegisterController` like this:

You can change form:

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('guest');

}
```

to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

public function __construct()
{

    Redirect::to('/')->send();

}
```

Note: for use `Redirect`  don't forget to  `user Redirect;` 
So user access to https://host_name/register it's redirect to "/".

## Method 2 for version 5.3

When we use `php artisan make:auth` it's added `Auth::route();` 
automatically.
Please Override Route in /routes/web.php.
You can change it's like this:
* you need to comment this line: `Auth::routes();`

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/


// Auth::routes();
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm' );
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Thanks! I hope it's can solve your problems.

Comment: I would add route names like specified in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');                                                                                               
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Comment: Redirect class missed on the first method, but changing to `$this->middleware('auth');` - works!

Answer (score 15):

> Set **Register route false**
> in your web.php.

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

-Worked in laravel 7

Comment: I am using Laravel 9.x version, your solution did not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: This will only work for **laravel/ui** package and should be mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Overwriting the getRegister and postRegister is tricky - if you are using git there is a high possibility that `.gitignore` is set to ignore framework files which will lead to the outcome that registration will still be possible in your production environment (if laravel is installed via composer for example)

Another possibility is using routes.php and adding this line:

```
Route::any('/auth/register','HomeController@index');
```

This way the framework files are left alone and any request will still be redirected away from the Frameworks register module.

Comment: The classes that override the framework methods are not in the framework (they would be in the app folder) and would be stored by git. Overriding methods does not mean you change them in the framework files.

Answer (score 12):

The `AuthController.php` @limonte has overridden is in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`, not in the vendor directory, so Git doesn't ignore this change.

I have added this functions:

```
public function register() {
    return redirect('/');
}

public function showRegistrationForm() {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

and it works correctly.

Answer (score 11):

LAravel 5.6

```
Auth::routes([
    'register' => false, // Registration Routes...
    'reset' => false, // Password Reset Routes...
    'verify' => false, // Email Verification Routes...
]);
```

Comment: This should be merged into the accepted answer, but just a minor correction. This feature was introduced in Laravel 5.7, not Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 8):

Heres my solution as of 5.4:

```
//Auth::routes();
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
//Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
//Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Notice I've commented out `Auth::routes()` and the two registration routes.

**Important:** you must also make sure you remove all instances of `route('register')` in your `app.blade` layout, or Laravel will throw an error.

Comment: ^ this. In case these routes ever change, simply copy/paste them from the Auth routes bundle located @ https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/92214c58578e836056b9272c3a641888380ae111/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1009 and comment out the registration routes.

Answer (score 8):

This has been mentioned in earlier comments but I would like to clarify that there are multiple ways to access the auth routes in your web.php file in Laravel ^5.7. depending on your version it might look a little different but they achieve the same result.

First option

```
Route::auth([
  'register' => false, // Registration Routes...
  'reset' => false, // Password Reset Routes...
  'verify' => false, // Email Verification Routes...
]);
```

Second option

```
Auth::routes([
  'register' => false, // Registration Routes...
  'reset' => false, // Password Reset Routes...
  'verify' => false, // Email Verification Routes...
]);
```

Answer (score 7):

**The following method works great:**

Copy all the routes from `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` and paste it into `web.php` and comment out or delete `Auth::routes()`.

Then setup a conditional to enable and disable registration from .env.
Duplicate the `503.blade.php` file in `views/errors` and create a 403 forbidden or whatever you like.

Add `ALLOW_USER_REGISTRATION=` to .env and control user registration by setting its value to true or false.

Now you have full control of routes and Vendor files remain untouched.

web.php

```
//Auth::routes();

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
if (env('ALLOW_USER_REGISTRATION', true))
{
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
}
else
{
    Route::match(['get','post'], 'register', function () {
        return view('errors.403');
    })->name('register');
}

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

This is a combination of some previous answers notably Rafal G. and Daniel Centore.

Answer (score 6):

In `routes.php`, just add the following:

```
if (!env('ALLOW_REGISTRATION', false)) {
    Route::any('/register', function() {
        abort(403);
    });
}
```

Then you can selectively control whether registration is allowed or not in you `.env` file.

Answer (score 6):

On laravel 5.6 and above you can edit in **web.php** file

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true, 'register' => false]);
```

and you can make it true if you change your mind, i see it easy this way

Answer (score 3):

I had to use:

```
public function getRegister()
{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Using Redirect::to() gave me an error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Redirect' not found
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this is new version feature, you can use this function or use preceding class, but preceding class needs \ before it, I means \Redirect::to('destination');

Answer (score 3):

## In Laravel 5.4

You can find all routes which are registered through `Auth::routes()` in the class `\Illuminate\Routing\Router` in the method `auth()`

it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

Just copy the routes that you want/need and you are fine!

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 5.3, you should override the default `showRegistrationForm()` by including the code below into the `RegisterController.php` file in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth`

```
    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        //return view('auth.register');
         abort(404);  //this will throw a page not found exception
    }
```

since you don't want to allow registration, it's better to just throw `404 error` so the intruder knows he is lost. And when you are ready for registraation in your app, uncomment `//return view('auth.register');` then comment `abort(404);`

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\JUST AN FYI///////////////////////////////

If you need to use multiple authentication like create auth for users, members, students, admin, etc. then i advise you checkout this [hesto/multi-auth](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth) its an awesome package for unlimited auths in L5 apps.

You can read more abouth the Auth methodology and its associated file in [this](http://robboyland.com/laravel-auth-how-to-disable-registration) writeup.

Comment: You also need to patch the post route so to avoid registration of user through post request.

Answer (score 2):

**In Laravel 5.5**

I was trying to accomplish the same problem in Laravel 5.5. Instead of using `Auth::routes()` in the web.php routes file, I only included the login/logout routes:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 8 with [Laravel Breeze](https://github.com/laravel/breeze), these auth routes are all explicitly listed in `routes/auth.php`. The registration routes are the first two at the top.

Just comment out the ones you don't want and Laravel takes care of the rest, eg. if you comment out the routes for `forgot-password` then there will be no "Forgot password?" link shown on the login window.

Answer (score 1):

For Fortify users, change config/fortify.php

```
'features' => [
    // Features::registration(), // --------> comment out this
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication(),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

for laravel with fortify like in (Laravel v8.52.0) you can just disable the registration feature in the fortify config file, for example

```
'features' => [
    //Features::registration(),
    //Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true,
    ]),
]
```

Comment: This was literally the last answer left on the question, 2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

In order not too change the code as it is, just create a middleware to detect if the request url is url('register'), then redirect to 404 or do wherever.

Comment: Very long run solution. A simple function override with abort can definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

**In Laravel 5.5**

Working on a similar issue and setting the middleware argument from guest to 'auth' seemed like a more elegant solution.

Edit File: app->http->Controllers->Auth->RegisterController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
     //replace this
     //$this->middleware('guest');

     //with this argument.
       $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I could be wrong though...but it seems more slick than editing the routing with more lines and less shity than simply redirecting the page...at least in this instance, wanting to lock down the registration for guests.

Comment: I'd be curious to know whether a user can register multiple times using this method. the `guest` middleware is responsible redirecting an already logged in user away from a page that only a guest can access (i.e. a `/register` page)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would rather be a better solution.

Override the following methods as below mentioned in

**App\Http\Controller\Auth\RegisterController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

.
.
.

public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5 is very simple, if you are using CRUD route system.

Go to `app/http/controllers/RegisterController`  there is namespace: `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUser`

You need to go to the RegistersUser: `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUser`

There is the method call `showRegistrationForm` change this: `return view('auth.login');` for this: `return redirect()->route('auth.login');` and remove from you blade page route call register. It may look like that:

```
 <li role="presentation">
     <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the easiest solution in laravel 5.6! It redirects anyone who tries to go to yoursite.com/register to yoursite.com

**routes/web.php**

```
// redirect from register page to home page
Route::get('/register', function () {
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was replace register blade code with login blade code. That way register still goes to login.

`resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` is replaced with `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.6+, paste the below methods in `app\Http\Controller\Auth\RegisterController`

```
/*
* Disabling registeration.
*
*/
public function register() 
{
    return redirect('/');
}

/*
* Disabling registeration.
*
*/
public function showRegistrationForm() 
{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Now you're overriding those methods in `RegistersUser` trait, whenever you change your mind remove these methods. You may also comment the register links in `welcome.blade.php` and `login.blade.php` views.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is too late, but any help will be good for others.
if your project **goes bigger** and you want to handle that **dynamically**.
you can add a **field in the settings table** as
**regestration_status**: boolean (of course you need to have a **settings table** if you need to **introduce some global variables or global settings**).

also, you can add that in the config file with its default status and call it when you need it.

so if registration == false just redirect the user to log in view with some errors message like:

> ' registration is closed at this moment please go back later '

or add another field to specify **from ... to** the date of registration when it opens.

and in the registration controller just make your logic (you can add it also in the store function to enforce the user):

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $settings= Setting::where('default': true)->first();
    if($settings->registration_status){
      return view('auth.register');
    }
      return redirect()->route('auth.login')->with('errors','registration 
      is closed at this moment please go back later');
}
```

Answer (score -12):

add

```
use \Redirect;
```

at the top of the file

Comment: You mean use \Redirect;

Comment: This is not a complete answer.

Comment: at the top of which file? the solution is incomplete and confusing.