# How to override Registration function in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to override the Registration function in Laravel 5 by following the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183348/how-to-disable-registration-new-user-in-laravel-5) question. In my case, however, I'm not trying to redirect users from the registration page. Rather, I'd like to just register the new user but keep the current (admin) user logged in. The default function validates then logs in the new user, then redirects to "home". So, here is what I tried adding to AuthController.php:

```
// OVERRIDE FUNCTION IN AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers (located under /Illuminate/Foundation/Auth)
public function postRegister(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    //$this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));
    $this->registrar->create($request->all());

    return redirect('admin');
}
```

I thought I was being clever and just causing the new account to be created, then redirecting the current user to an admin page. However, no user is being created and the redirect is not happening. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Another default behavior that you may want to change is auto-login immediately after the registration form. You may want to redirect your user to a separate “success” page and expect them to log in manually later.

To do that, you need to override register() method of a trait RegistersUsers.

The controller we discussed above, RegisterController, uses this important Trait:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
use RegistersUsers;
// ... all other code of controller
This trait performs all the “dirty work” of registration. It is part of the core 
framework, located in 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php:

trait RegistersUsers
{
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

// ... A few other methods

}
```

To disable auto-login, you need to delete this particular line:

```
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

But you can’t edit directly Laravel core, or any part of what’s inside /vendor. What you can do is override the same method and put it in your RegisterController, like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

// DON'T FORGET TO ADD THESE TWO!
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

// ... Other methods

/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

}
```

Finally, take care of redirectTo parameter or method, as shown in previous tip, so your registered user would land on a correct page.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd rather use the "create" static method in my Model, for example: for registration I use "User" model, then I just had to simply use:

```
User::create($data = array());
```

it will just store data to the table in the User model. Then simply:

```
return redirect('admin');
```

And the new user wouldn't be logged in to the site. It just store a data to table in database.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I probably should just do something along the lines that you are suggesting, but I am still curious as to why my override code is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: really? try to override its method, not in the 'AuthenticatesAndRegisterUsers' class but on your 'AuthController' located at 'Http/Controllers/Auth/'. I have tested that on my own laravel project and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: @JHolmes Im facing the same issue here, I lost my entire day trying to find some solution but still doesnt work. Did you found the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at artisan rout:list, where is postRegister being called ?

You need to override the register function.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer,(in my case).
I copied the register function and forgot to remove confirmed validation in the email