# How to disable registration new user in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use laravel 5.6

I want to disable registration for new users, of course the login form must work

I see below question :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183348/how-to-disable-registration-new-user-in-laravel-5
```

But I did not find the ‍‍`showRegistrationForm()` function on the following path:

`Auth/RegisterController.php`

Comment: You will not see this method. just put those codes on the controller and it should work. It is overridden.

Comment: Thanks . Finally, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In routes/web.php do:

`Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`

It works for me.

Comment: FYI - a note about how to disable registration using this method has been added to the Laravel 5.7 docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#included-routing

Answer (score 2):

You may use middleware auth in RegisterController :

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

instead of :

```
$this->middleware('guest');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

insted of :

```
$this->middleware('guest');
```

and you can use register again by copying

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

form RegisterUser.php to Register controller which follow OOP overriding method

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `use RegistersUsers;` trait from the `Auth/RegisterController`; This trait (located in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`) handles the register form.

The routes are registered in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` in the `auth()` method.

After removing the trait, the routes are probably still in effect due to the stuff mentioned above. So to keep a good working app, write your own `showRegistrationForm()` and `register()` methods in the `Auth/RegisterController.php` where you redirect both methods to something like the login route or the homepage.

Comment: Thanks . in this file `Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php` only `use RedirectsUsers;`

Comment: No, remove the line `use RegistersUsers;` in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` (somewhere around line 24).

Answer (score 0):

In `routes/web.php` you can do:

```
Route::any('/auth/register','HomeController@index');
```