# Laravel 5.7 login & registration page are not working: refreshing the appropriate pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

guys! I am new to Laravel, and working on project, using the following technologies:
Laravel Framework 5.7.15
XAMPP for Windows 7.2.1
PHP version: 7.2.1
Apache/2.4.29
MySQL: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev

Everything worked fine: the login, and the registration. And then I wanted to restrict registration to the app. So I found below solution to the problem on StackOverflow:
[How to disable registration new user in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183348/how-to-disable-registration-new-user-in-laravel-5) 
So I added it to app/Http/Controlers/Auth/RegisterController.php:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return redirect('login');
}

public function register()
{

}
```

After that (or may be something else, but I am not sure) the login page redirects to login page without logging in to the system. Similarly, registration page (which I remember was redirecting to the login page) is also refreshing the page without registering me to the system.

What I did to solve the problem:
1) I removed the above methods from the file. The pages do not work as intended. Both pages refresh and do not give any errors.
2) I removed my database and migrates again. No results.

I just do not want to recreate the project because of this problem, and I hope that someone can help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what do you want now? Do you want to restrict user to go registration page?  And do you want to only allow user to login?

Comment: I want to be able to log in to the system

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict user to go registration page and only allowing other Authentication functionalities, then dont change any controller just change below route i ln web.php

```
Auth::routes();
```

to

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

If you had removed database tables for auth, restore it before making this changes.

Comment: Restricting the registration I did with the above methods also. But the main problem is that I cannot log in to the system. It refreshes the page instead of checking the validation

Comment: Show me your login controller.

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
   

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}

Comment: Just overwrite this function below " use AuthenticatesUsers; " paste this line public function showLoginForm()
    {
     return view('auth.login');
    }    in your login controller.

Comment: I pasted the method in the file, but nothing has changed, I would like to mention that the login form loads properly [with/without the above method], but the problem is that when you enter the credentials and click on LOGIN button, the page refreshes and cleans the form, instead of checking the password and login validation :(

Comment: Check your database user table. Does it have credentials??

Comment: I have inserted a user to the table. But the form acts differently. It should check that the user exists or not, and etc. But it does not check anything. Just refreshes and that is it

Comment: Do you think that a missing any HTML opening/closing tag can cause such problem? Or it is only something to do with the laravel itself?

Comment: the code is long for putting in comment, so I put it here: https://codepen.io/Saidmamad/pen/qLEMOr?editors=1000