# Override default Auth routes in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I use default `auth` route in my web.php .

This routes copied of `Illuminate/Routing/Router.php' .

I use this for change default route and ... in `web.php`

```php
Route::group([], function (){

    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    }

    // Password Reset Routes...
    if ($options['reset'] ?? true) {
        $this->resetPassword();
    }

    // Email Verification Routes...
    if ($options['verify'] ?? false) {
        $this->emailVerification();
    }
});
```

What is `$options[]` ??

Where should I define it in my route group ?

Thanks for help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method inside `Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` is not intended to be copied like you did. Normally, it should be used with the `Auth` Facade, like this: `Auth::routes($options);`. This call the `route()` method and should be done inside a route file, typically `web.php` if you didn't change anything.

This way, the options are indeed taken into account. Now, in your case, their is no need for an optional `$options` array, since you hard copied the routes.

To avoid any errors in your route file, you have two choices:

1) Use `Auth::routes()` (with the options array if needed). You can of course override the routes you want to change.

2) Dig into the `emailVerification` and `resetPassword` method in order to copy/paste the routes they refer to, and delete any reference to `$this` and `$options` inside your route file

Comment: Thanks, @toyi. I was cracking my head to fix an issue. Your answer was helpful..

Answer (score 0):

The `$options` array is used to configure the registeration as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52746872/7528944). So it's used for specifying whether you'd like to enable or disable user registeration, password reset and email verification.

Comment: very thanks . but where should I define it in my route group ?

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely see don't any reason to overwrite the default group. Just remove `Auth::routes()`, from web.php, and implement your own routes, according to the controllers.